# AngularJS: Asynchronous $http.get calls causing issues on View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In my app I'm using two distinct API calls - the first pulls a catalog of services and their unique ID's, then, once I have the ID's, I pull the pricing for that service. However I am having issues whereby the second GET request is being hit hundreds of times per page load and causing memory issues in Chrome & Firefox.

On my view, I have the following;

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in catalog track by $index">
    <td>{{ c.id }}</td> 
    <td>{{ c.name }}</td> 
    <td>{{ c.description }}</td> 
    <td>{{ c.service_status }}</td> 
    <td>{{ getService(c.id) }} {{services}} </td>  
</tr>
```

My two "API calls" (simplified below) are in factories & using promises as follows;

```
app.factory('catalogDataFactory', function($http){
    var getCatalog = function() {
    // next line is the result of an API call for testing purposes
        return $http.get("../data/catalog.json").then(function (result){
            return result.data;
        });
    };
    return { getCatalog: getCatalog };
});



app.factory('servicesDataFactory', function($http){

    var service = {};
    var baseURL = '../data/'; 
    var _guid = '';

    service.setGuid = function(guid){
        console.log("setGuid is being called too many times with input: " + guid); // appears hundreds of times per minute
        _guid = guid;
    }

    service.callAPI = function(){
        console.log("callAPI is being called too many times"); // appears hundreds of times per minute
        return $http.get(baseURL + _guid + ".json").then(function (result){
                return result.data;
        });

    }

    return service;
});
```

And my controller looks like this;

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $compile, catalogDataFactory, servicesDataFactory, utilities) {

    $scope.catalog = []
    $scope.service = [];

    catalogDataFactory.getCatalog().then(function(result) {
        $scope.catalog = result.data[0]['services'].data; // iterate through JSON to find data array
        console.log("getCatalog is being called too many times"); // called hundreds of times per minute
        $scope.getService = function (guid){
            console.log("getService is being called too many times"); // called hundreds of times per minute
            servicesDataFactory.setGuid(guid);
            // return servicesDataFactory.callAPI();
            $scope.service = servicesDataFactory.callAPI();
        };

    }); // end of catalog promise

}); // end of controller
```

I'm getting the following error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D and my browser is freezing up. If I have the open beforehand then I can see the errors mounting up (same error thousands of times) and the `console.logs` appearing over and over again.

My question is ... should I be using a Service (rather than a factory) for the second API call? Or does my code need changed in more fundamental ways?

Comment: Why do you  define getService inside getCatalog? Can you pull this out?

Comment: maybe in getCatalog() just return the $http.get instead of $http.get().then()

Comment: @mavarazy I nested them as getService is reliant on the results of getCatalog. However I did test them non-nested and got the same issue.

Comment: @glcheetham I need to use .then() because I'm using promises for the get() request. The API can be a little slow so promises are necessary.

Comment: Does it work if you don't call getService in your template?

Answer (score 0):

First it's a bad practice to call a function from within ng-repeat since a call to getService will be made on every $digest cycle. That will happen on any scope changes or any http callbacks. Perhaps that's why you get so many calls.

I suggest that instead of having a getService method you either create return a dictionary of catalogs and their services from the server or build one ad the controllers is invoked. Then in you ng-repeat you can simply get the service value from that dictionary.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try today as it makes sense. Good to note that calling a function in ng-repeat is bad practice.

Comment: Turns out my problem was a little more complex, will add an answer.